# Why do I need Babel JS?

Tags: babeljs

I'm struggling to understand the importance of Babel here... So ES6 comes along and gives us fat arrow functions, shorter syntax etc. so why do we need to compile ES6 into traditional JS? Is it because there are older browsers out there that can't interpret new JS syntax? Or does it have something to do with keeping source code consistent? Bit of a noob question I know - but hey, I am noob!
Any insight appreciated!

Comment: Yes, because not everything supports ES6. Also, say if you're using React or JSX, babel needs to be there to transpile it.

Comment: I think that ES6 will be official in sometime, but today it's really hard to change the web development to the new standard because there is a lot of websites that wouldn't run otherwise. Guys from browser developing will need to create something that would read es6 and es5, so that you can access all of websites even if there are not code-updated. We will see how it goes :) 

And I'm actually just guessing, nothing official in my comment.

Comment: @DawidZbiński ES6 already is official. And there is nothing complicated about old scripts, the new standard is backwards-compatible, every ES5 is valid ES6 as well.

Answer (score 37):

While the answers here are all correct, Babel is not just about ES6 (ES2015).  The ECMA standards committee has agreed to release yearly updates to the JavaScript language.  Babel will *always* integrate the standards, whereas we don't know if all the browsers will, and if they do, whether they will be able to keep up with the changing standards.

With a transpiler like Babel, we can stay ahead of the web browsers and use new features of ECMAscript when they are released instead of waiting for the browser manufacturers to integrate the features, use polyfills, or whatever else.  It also allows the end user to customize the features that they want to use and build their own version of the language.

To hear the creator of Babel talk about this, you can listen to [this JavaScript Jabber episode](https://devchat.tv/js-jabber/171-jsj-babel-with-sebastian-mckenzie).

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yes I listened to part of that episode in the car the other day... Young Aussie like me : )

Comment: Awesome!   I learned about Babel from using it over the last year.  To me, JavaScript is a completely new language with the new features.  We have async await to look forward to, for example, which in my opinion is an absolute game changer for anyone who's been writing callbacks for a long time.  It makes the code more understandable, which is huge.  Understandable code equals maintainable code.  Babel is completely awesome and I'd completely recommend making it a part of your toolchain.

Comment: Heck, with all these experimental plugins and stage-0-presets, most people are using the newest features even *before* they are released. (like e.g. async/await, which is not part of ES6 or ES7).

Answer (score 6):

Most modern browsers has almost full support es6 today. From 96% to 99% support.

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

The main thing missing is ES6 modules. Currently only Safari supports ES6 modules. Support for ES6 modules should arrive in Google Chrome 60.

In order to get the ES6 code to run you have to combine you ES6 code modules into one JavaScript file using a bundler like Browserify or Webpack. I had good luck with using Webpack 3.0 for bundling.

Babel is responsible to converting new language features to old.

You can write code that would run on many browser by using just the bundler but without using Babel. You code does become more convoluted by transpiling it with Babel, so you should only do this if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

Not all browsers support ES6. Along with transpiling things like React.

http://www.webbrowsercompatibility.com/es6/desktop/

Answer (score 3):

I might be late for answering this question but the main reason for me is because even Node version 12 doesn't support the ES6 module system (import and export keywords).

Babel transpiles ES6 syntax to CommonJS, which saves a lot of headaches

Answer (score 1):

You got it right. There are tons of browsers that haven't support/partly support es6 so you still need to interpret to traditional js for coming years. 
Especially when customers are complaining that your website doesn't work on their IE6 browser